# Когда нужно выравнивание?

Tags: алгоритм, кроссплатформенность, c++

Имеется код для вычисления длинны строки (оптимизированный под большие строки)

```
    #define STDCALL __stdcall
const size_t STDCALL strlen4( const char * str )
{
    const char* p = str;
    while ((DWORD_PTR)p & 3)
    {
        if (!*p)
        {
            return p - str;
        }
        ++p;
    }
    DWORD v = *(DWORD*)p;
    while(!(((~v) ^ (v + 0x7efefeff)) & 0x81010100))
    {
        p += 4;
        v = *(DWORD*)p;
    }
    const size_t l = p - str;
    if (v & 0xff)
    {
        if (v & 0xff00)
        {
            if (v & 0xff0000)
            {
                return l + 3;
            }
            return l + 2;
        }
        return l + 1;
    }
    return l;
}
```

Как мне подсказали цикл while ((DWORD_PTR)p & 3) служит для обнаружения длинны строки с том случае когда 32-битные целые не выравнены на границы 4х байт.

```
while ((DWORD_PTR)p & 3)
    {
        if (!*p)
        {
            return p - str;
        }
        ++p;
    }
```

Вот только я не как не могу понять в каких случаях может так получится, что число(в данном случае часть строки) будет не выравнено на границы 4х байт?(т.е. условие цикла будет верно) Подскажите пожалуйста...
И ещё не совсем понимаю само условие цикла:(DWORD_PTR)p & 3... Как (DWORD_PTR)p - адресс в памяти позволяет опраделить что число выровнено или невыровнено?
Если есть статьи по этом поводу то буду рад если подскажите где можно их прочитать... А то чегото совсем не понимаю я про выравнивание... Подскажите пожалуйста....

Comment: Откровенно говоря, *while (константное по сути выражение)* в **оптимизированном коде** выглядит издевательством (или лох писал, или развод лохов).

Answer (score 3):

Непонятно когда часть стороки не выровняна на границу слова ?

Очень просто. Допустим char str[1000]; и str[0] выровняно, тогда str+1 не выровняно.

В некоторых процессорах обращение к целому (DWORD v) в памяти возможно только если его адрес выровнян не границу слова. Иначе будет прерывание (допустим SYGBUS). В других обращение к невыровненным словам медленнее, чем к выровненным.

Видимо Вы работаете с x86 на достаточно современном компьютере. Прерываний однозначно не будет, IMHO скорость будет одна и та же, чт с выровненными словами, что нет.

А вообще напишите тестики с измерением скорости и доложите сообществу.

По поводу как p & 3 определяет выравнивание. Если адрес выровнян на границу слова, то он кратен четырем, другими словами младшие 2 бита у него нулевые, т.е.

```
if (p & 3)
    // невыровнян, в младших 2-х битах есть единички
else
    // выровнян
```

Ну, а while() можно рассматривать как разновидность if () (Я серьезно. Можно, только **очень неудобно** написать программу вообще без операторов if (заменяя их на while и устанавливая разные флаги.))

Comment: Спасибо, во всём разобрался.